UART reading performance at high baud rates (FTDI + Windows)
I have an FPGA digitizer connected via FTDI FT4232 USB-UART converter to my Windows 10 computer. The communication speed is 5 Mega Bauds, 8N1. I am trying to read 1048576 bytes of data which is sent as a response to a simple text command. Data is protected by a CRC32 checksum (transferred using another command).
Everything works quite well with RealTerm terminal emulator, and now I need to do the same thing with my C#.NET application. Having read some real experience with the SerialPort class, I currently have the code below. The approach is simple: There is a dedicated reader thread which reads data from the serial port and pushes it to a producer-consumer queue, from which data is read by another thread.
_PicoblazeReadBuffer = new ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>();
_Port = new SerialPort("COM12", 5000000, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
_PicoblazeReaderThreadCanceller = new CancellationTokenSource();
_PicoblazeReaderThread = new Thread(ReaderThread) {
    Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest,
    IsBackground = true,
};
_PicoblazeReaderThread.Start(_PicoblazeReaderThreadCanceller.Token);

...

private void ReaderThread(object cancellationTokenAsObject)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[131072];
    int bufferOffset = 0;
    CancellationToken token = (CancellationToken)cancellationTokenAsObject; 

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    while (_Port.IsOpen && !token.IsCancellationRequested) {
        try {
            int readLength = Math.Min(4096, buffer.Length - bufferOffset);
            int actualLength = _Port.BaseStream.Read(buffer, bufferOffset, readLength);
            if (actualLength > 0) {
                bufferOffset += actualLength;
                if (bufferOffset >= 65535 || stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 100) {
                    byte[] chunk = new byte[bufferOffset];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, chunk, 0, bufferOffset);
                    _PicoblazeReadBuffer.Enqueue(chunk);
                    _PicoblazeReadSemaphore.Release();
                    bufferOffset = 0;
                    stopwatch.Restart();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

The problem: Some data get lost during the transfer, and therefore my consumer thread times out. When I tried to save the intermediate result, it seems the data always get trimmed at the end, but the beginning is valid.

When I increase the Latency Timer from default 16 ms to at least 60 ms, the reading completes successfully. I cannot understand, why this happens, because if I understand it correctly, the latency timer should affect performance only when I send short data packets.
Although I want to read 4096 bytes (default driver buffer size), the function completes earlier and returns only 250 bytes on average. Therefore, I added a simple data packing condition, which reduces the overhead related to the queue locking. This issue might be connected to the event characters, which forces the chip to flush out the buffers, but the problem persists even if I send all-zero pattern from the FPGA.

Do you have any experience with high baud-rate data transfers in C#?

Looks like you're missing a brace in ReaderThread. Is that indicative of some other problem, which could cause you not to go around that while loop?

What is _PicoblazeReadBuffer? Is there any way that could be losing data?

@canton7: I accidentally deleted the brace when I was cutting down the code for Stackoverflow. Now it's fixed. _PicoblazeReadBuffer is ConcurrentQueue<byte[]>.

Righty, so that won't block. As an aside, any reason not to use a BlockingCollection, rather than rolling your own with semaphores?

@canton7: I need async TryDequeue() method which neither of the collections support. Therefore I emulate it using the SemaphoreSlim.

I do not use C#.net but I have mode good experiences with using the actually available data in the receive buffer. So something like bufferOffset += _Port.BaseStream.Read(buffer, bufferOffset,  _Port.BytesToRead); followed by a short thread yield/sleep(0).
